# purpose of JPanel?

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

This write up on JPanel seems to focus on this container as a means of setting a background color. [Oracle on how to use JPanel](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/panel.html)  Should I infer that if I am happy with the default grey background in ubuntu/gnome/Java programs, there is no need to use this object?  Is there an object-oriented programming reason to use this object?

Comment: If you are going to do any Swing programming,  you are going to be using JPanels, and in fact should gear most of your GUI's towards producing JPanels rather than JFrames or other top-level containers.

Comment: Is there a reason to use more than one JPanel per JFrame when I am not fussy about color and borders?

Comment: Yes. Each JPanel can act as a container for any number of components and can use its own layout. If you create all but the most simple of GUI's you'll be using several JPanels.

Comment: Um, you're not going to delete this question like the other, are you?

Comment: I hope to keep it.  Not sure which one got deleted other than my english.stackexchange one today.  I had unsatisfactory behaviour putting a JScrollPane inside a JPanel in a JPanel.  It was better not to have the intermediate JPanel but reading Oracle, I would have no idea why.

Comment: You deleted one I had worked on quite a bit several days ago. It's very frustrating putting volunteer effort trying to answer someone's question only to see them delete the question. Makes me hesitant to help you again.

Comment: Perhaps Oracle should write: JPanel is not about color.  It can do stuff that takes work and experience to understand.

Comment: Hovercraft: It might have been the exact same topic about 20 hours back and the delete happened before I saw your attempted post (otherwise SO would probably not allow a delete.)  I remember I got a sarcastic comment and may be close-votes possibly because some people thought it was an opinion question.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

JPanels are a way to create a logical "division" of space if that makes any sense.  For example, if you think about HTML, you could just put elements one after another on the page (how some old HTML pages look in fact) but it's much more aesthetically pleasing to use a container like a table, or some CSS styled DIV tags to create divisions on the page, and place elements relative to one another in a much more defined manner.

JPanels fill this function in Swing, where each JPanel has a Layout Manager that defines how it's inner elements are laid out.  It's not unusual to nest JPanels, for example, using a JPanel with a border layout for the menus/status bar, etc, a JPanel at the center of that with further elements, and then additional JPanels inside of that central "content panel" area that further divides the space, for example, creating an input form on one part of the central panel.

In this sense, JPanels are quite comparable to how Tables and Divs are used in HTML, and you should think of them in a similar manner when creating your layout. The most important thing about JPanels is their ability to dynamically resize, pushing the contained components around.  If you just used, say, one JPanel and absolutely positioned everything, then you'd lose the main appeal of Swing, and this container methodology.

Answer (score 3):

It's quite possible you perceived the authors angle to be one slanted towards color and drawing, but I think if you give the blog a second read you will find that he was indeed trying to be more expansive than that. JPanel's can and are used as content panes for a variety of other widgets in a typical Swing application.

Also I'm not sure why you reference Ubuntu/Gnome, as the L&F of a platform is quite divorced from the utility of JPanel.

Comment: To quote from Oracle: "Like other containers, a panel uses a layout manager to position and size its components."  Makes it sound like JPanels are completely redundant and accordingly unnecessary given the abilities of other containers.

Comment: Or perhaps Oracle should rewrite the JPanel introduction.